# An alien language?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

[image: What am I?]

This is a teaser puzzle for our upcoming puzzle book Codex Enigmatum - launching on Kickstarter soon.

Comment: Let's leave the solution to a Tardis :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

it looks like it

> says "I Break when you say my name"

Because

> the letters are reflected either horizontally or vertically and "when you say my" is written vertically

So therefore

> the answer to the riddle is "Silence"